# How to build opencv_contrib 3.1.0 as of 6.2.2016. on linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I have a problem building opencv with opencv_contrib on linux 15.10 and linux 14.04 as of 6.2.2016.

I was already able to build it once about a week and a half ago but since then I've run into a problem which the newest version of opencv should fix.

Anyway, these are the commands that I am running to make a cmake file:

`cd /home/ila
mkdir openCVbuild
cd openCVbuild
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ila/openCVbuild/opencv_contrib BUILD_DOCS=YES BUILD_EXAMPLES=YES /home/ila/openCVbuild/opencv`

When I do that, I get this error in the terminal:

`-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ila/openCVbuild/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ila/openCVbuild/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Oh, now I see... Looks like I've become illiterate since the last time I've built it.

So the problem is the path of the contrib modules...
I put:`OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ila/openCVbuild/opencv_contrib`
instead of `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ila/openCVbuild/opencv_contrib/modules`

"Problem" solved! Hope it helps if anyone has this dumb mistake. :)